# How to display successful and failed HTTP calls to `/status` in Prometheus/Grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

This is rather a question for serverfault but I did not get an answer there https://serverfault.com/questions/1024285/is-it-possible-to-display-successful-queries-of-an-arbitrary-endpoint-in-prometh, and I have seen `prometheus` related questions here without any complaint...so trying my luck :)

We have nodes which offer a status endpoint as a plain simple GET:

```
GET /status
```

It returns just simple 200 if all is ok, otherwise an error code. No body nor additional data returned.

I would like to display this in Grafana via Prometheus, but I did not succeed. Basically a metric for every successful `status` call and probably one for failed ones.

`/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml` is configured to call the endpoint:

```
  - job_name: 'status'
    scrape_interval: 60s
    metrics_path: /status
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['<IP1>:12345']
      - targets: ['<IP2>:12345']
```

I can not see anything related to this call in prometheus (and thus nor in Grafana). The `promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total` for example is empty (or at least not for this job) - I suppose that is because the endpoint isn't actually returning any data.

Is it possible to display a history of successful status calls, or at least the current (or last) status in a Grafana dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

The config which you wrote is basically to scrape metrics that are already exposed at /status path; I don't think it will work for your requirement.

One easy way to achieve if you are just after the health of that endpoint is to use Prometheus Blackbox exporter -

https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter

This will test the endpoint and then expose a metric.

You need to run this as a service/docker container as per your choice and then

and then in your Prometheus config; you can write a static job to scrape that metric.

```
- job_name: 'blackbox'
  metrics_path: /probe
  params:
    module: [http_2xx]  # Look for a HTTP 200 response.
  static_configs:
    - targets:
      - <HOST URL/IP - you want to check>
  relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__address__]
      target_label: __param_target
    - source_labels: [__param_target]
      target_label: instance
    - target_label: __address__
      replacement: <Blackbox Host/IP:PORT>
```

and then you can make use of this metric in Grafana.

It should be available with the name - "probe_success"

Comment: interesting, totally different approach, will look into this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the records:

I ended up writing my own exporter. It queries the needed endpoints and just writes the results in prometheus format to a port which is configured to get scraped by the server.